# Connection problems using openvpn on android

Tags: networking, vpn, android, openvpn

I have set up my own openvpn-server on a ubuntu 19.10. It works fine when i connect with my PC, i can connect to the server without problems. But when I try to connect with my smartphone (Android 6.0.1) with the app 'OpenVPN Connect' the app says that openvpn is connected but i cannot reach any service on the server.

When a make a ping (with 'Network Analyzer') he get's no response from the server and in the openvpn log i see 'UDP send exception: send: Operation not permitted'.

It seems to be more a network/right problem on my smartphone than a (configuration)problem of openVPN. But currently i have no idea anymore.

I would appreciate it if someone can give me a hint what i should check or tell me how i may fix this problem.

Comment: Getting the same error message on Android 6.0.1, but not always, so the tunnel works some amount of time,. But after putting the phone aside, at some point the tunnel fails and I need to use the phone again to reestablish the tunnel. So might have to do with sleep modes or stuff like that as well. Disabled everything I could find in this direction already, but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Asked in the OVPN-forums as well: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=29990

Comment: Somewhat similar error messages are related to `nf_conntrack` and Android seems to support at least some kind of `iptables`/`netfilter`: http://sip-router.1086192.n5.nabble.com/UDP-send-Operation-not-permitted-td141385.html https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/bcmdhd-3.10/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_iptables https://stackoverflow.com/a/16857477/2055163